# Problem with Flutter Web. Chrome Beta is uninstalled but still showing up

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, dart, flutter-web

I am facing a problem with the flutter web initialization. I followed the steps in https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web Everything went smooth

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
```

When I do Flutter Doctor I get

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.17.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find chrome executable at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome Beta\Application)
    ! C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome Beta\Application is not executable.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I don't have chrome beta on my PC anymore. I have normal chrome. How to change it. Somebody help me out.
Also, I got found this online as a solution but I don't know what it means.

```
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=path/to/chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ***not the solution*** but an ***alternative method*** you can try. If you are in the beta channel of flutter you can just type `flutter build web` that will create a web build in your web folder. You can run it on any other server just like normal web application. If you want to do this to an existing project first run `flutter create .` then `flutter build web`.